# Why does this script work in Kali Linux but not Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to run a script on Ubuntu that I have built in Kali Linux (where it runs perfectly), however, it will not run on Ubuntu.

I have changed the shebang to match the Bash location in Ubuntu, run the script as ./myscript.sh and bash myscript.sh but no luck. Interestingly the commands do work when copied into the Ubuntu Bash Terminal.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Imported variables
source <(grep -E '^\w+=' /root/scripts/variables.sh)
ZONE_ID=$zoneID
cloudflareAPItoken=$cloudflareAPItoken
domainName=$domainName
serverName=$servername

function help {
    echo "This is the help test"
}

findID () {
    curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE_ID/dns_records" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $cloudflareAPItoken" \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    | $(python3 -c "import sys,json
data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read())

if data['success']:
    for item in data['result']:
        if item['name']=='$OPTARG.emailtesting.co.uk':
            f = open('demofile.txt', 'w')
            f.write(item['id'])
            f.close()") 
}


deleteDNS () {
    curl -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE_ID/dns_records/$(cat demofile.txt)" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $cloudflareAPItoken" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    | python -m json.tool;
    rm demofile.txt 
}


listAllDNS () {
    curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE_ID/dns_records" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $cloudflareAPItoken" \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    | $(python -c $"import sys,json, re
data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read())
f = open('dnsLIST.txt', 'w')
if data['success']:
    for dict in data['result']:
        if dict['type'] == 'A' and dict['name'] != '$domainName':           
            f.write(dict['name'] + '\n')

            
else:
    print('ERROR(' + str(data['errors'][0]['code']) + '): ' + data['errors'][0]['message'])
    
f.close()

fin = open('dnsLIST.txt', 'r')
fout = open('dnsLISTredone.txt', 'w')

for line in fin:
    new_line = re.sub(r'(.+)($domainName)$',r'\1',line)
    new_line=new_line[:-2] + '\n'
    fout.write(new_line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
    
")

}


addSubDomain () {
    curl -s -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE_ID/dns_records" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $cloudflareAPItoken" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data "{\"type\":\"A\",\"name\":\"$OPTARG\",\"content\":\"$serverName\",\"ttl\":120,\"proxied\":false}" | jq
}

if [[ ${#} -eq 0 ]]; then
    help
    exit 1
fi

optstring="hd:la:"
while getopts ${optstring} arg; do
    case ${arg} in
        h)
            help;;
    d)
        findID
        deleteDNS
        exit 1
        ;;
    l) 
        listAllDNS;;
    a)
        addSubDomain;;
        ?)
            echo "Invalid option: -${OPTARG}."
            exit 2;;
    esac
done
```

Nothing happens when running `./myscript -a word`.

When running `./myscript -d word`, I get the following error:

```
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you

Comment: what happens if you just run the curl command manually?

Comment: I suggest to paste the script at https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the errors/warnings. Please explain the purpose of `curl  ...    | $(python -c $" ... ")`. The `$( ... )` expands to the output of the `python ...` command, so it will try to run this output as a command of the pipe. Run your script with `bash -x myscript.sh` and check what actually gets executed.

Comment: Check how `/root/scripts/variables.sh` is different on both systems. And then try to narrow it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Seems http related. Try workaround of adding --http1.1 to curl?